# How to access all directives on selected fields of a query, with GraphQL Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

I have an authentication directive, used to restrict fields to certain authentication levels

```
directive @auth(role: [String!]!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

For example, with the following schema

```
type Query {
    test: TestResultType! @auth(role: ["USER", "ADMIN"]) 
}

type TestResultType {
    customer: Customer!
    seller: Seller!
}

type Customer {
    email: String!
    username: String!
    password: String! @auth(role: "ADMIN")
}

type Seller {
    brandName: String!
    email: String!
    username: String!
    password: String! @auth(role: "ADMIN")
}
```

The query `test` would be restricted to either `"USER"` or `"ADMIN"`, and the `password` field of both `Customer` and `Seller` are restricted to only `"ADMIN"`.

If I have the authorization level of `"USER"`, but not `"ADMIN"`, then the following query should go through just fine because I am not requesting anything that is protected with the `@auth(role: "ADMIN")` directive

```
query {
    test {
        customer {
            email
        }
        seller {
            brandName
            email
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I have the authorization level of `"USER"`, but not `"ADMIN"`, then the following query should return an error since I selected the `password` fields in the query, which is protected with the `@auth(role: "ADMIN")` directive

```
query {
    test {
        customer {
            email
            password
        }
        seller {
            brandName
            email
            password
        }
    }
}
```

To work with directives in Spring Boot GraphQL, I must register a `SchemaDirectiveWiring` with a `RuntimeWiringConfigurer` bean. I have registered `AuthorizationDirective`

```java
public class AuthorizationDirective implements SchemaDirectiveWiring {

    @Override
    public GraphQLFieldDefinition onField(
            SchemaDirectiveWiringEnvironment<GraphQLFieldDefinition> wiringEnv) {
        // Get current data fetcher
        GraphQLFieldsContainer fieldsContainer = wiringEnv.getFieldsContainer();
        GraphQLFieldDefinition fieldDefinition = wiringEnv.getFieldDefinition();
        final DataFetcher<?> currentDataFetcher = wiringEnv
                .getCodeRegistry()
                .getDataFetcher(fieldsContainer, fieldDefinition);

        // Apply data fetcher with authorization logic
        final DataFetcher<?> authorizingDataFetcher = buildAuthorizingDataFetcher(
                wiringEnv,
                currentDataFetcher);
        wiringEnv.getCodeRegistry()
                .dataFetcher(
                        fieldsContainer,
                        fieldDefinition,
                        authorizingDataFetcher);

        return fieldDefinition;
    }

    private DataFetcher<Object> buildAuthorizingDataFetcher(
            SchemaDirectiveWiringEnvironment<GraphQLFieldDefinition> wiringEnv,
            DataFetcher<?> currentDataFetcher) {
        return fetchingEnv -> {
            // Implementation here
        };
    }
}
```

Where I am lost is, how do I extract the REQUESTED fields and information from either the `SchemaDirectiveWiringEnvironment<GraphQLFieldDefinition>` or `DataFetchingEnvironment` objects, that are available to me in the `buildAuthorizingDataFetcher()` function. I managed to extract ALL fields from `wiringEnv` by performing a breadth-first traversal like this:

```java
Queue<GraphQLSchemaElement> nodeQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(
        wiringEnv.getElement().getType().getChildren());

while (!nodeQueue.isEmpty()) {
    var node = nodeQueue.remove();
    if (GraphQLFieldDefinition.class.isAssignableFrom(node.getClass()))
        // Perform logic on graphql field node
        System.out.println(((GraphQLFieldDefinition) node).getName());
    nodeQueue.addAll(node.getChildren());
}
```

And I could also see how I could do something similar with `fetchingEnv`, however, I don't want ALL fields of a query, I only want the ones selected by the user. Is there a way to access this information?

EDIT:
I found a way to get a list of all the selections:

```java
fetchingEnv.getSelection().getFields();
```

This returns a list of `SelectedField`, which is exactly what I wanted, however, these `SelectedField` objects lack any information about directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

The following code snippet will return an object of type `List<SelectedField>`

```java
var selectionSet = fetchingEnv.getSelectionSet().getFields();
```

Then, you can iterate through this list to extract the `List<GraphQLFieldDefinition>` object from your selection set.

```java
var fieldDefs = selectionSet.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getFieldDefinitions().stream())
        .toList()
```

Finally, you can extract the `List<GraphQLDirective>` object from the field definitions.

```java
var directives = fieldDefs.stream()
        .map(f -> f.getDirective("name"))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toList();
```

And then you can perform all sorts of other checks on the directives that you need.